# Function averaging values in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 3 dictionaries:

```
zosia = {'imie': 'Zosia', 'zadania': 1, 'quizy': 2, 'testy': 5 },

jas = {'imie': 'Jas', 'zadania': 5, 'quizy': 5, 'testy': 5 },

malgosia = {'imie': 'Malgosia', 'zadania': 3, 'quizy': 3, 'testy': 4 }
```

And list that contains them:

```
studenci = [zosia, jas, malgosia]
```

I need to create a function that averages values ('zadania','quizy','testy') in all dictionaries contained in studenci list. So basically I need average of studenci. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I could only access only one value in those dictionaries and I didn't know how to access all of these values. Didn't know how to chain them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just chain the values and use `sum()` and `len()` to average them. Note that you cannot have a comma after the dicts in your question; that wraps them into tuples.

```
from __future__ import division # only use this if you are in python 2.7
from itertools import chain

zosia = {'imie': 'Zosia', 'zadania': 1, 'quizy': 2, 'testy': 5 }
jas = {'imie': 'Jas', 'zadania': 5, 'quizy': 5, 'testy': 5 }
malgosia = {'imie': 'Malgosia', 'zadania': 3, 'quizy': 3, 'testy': 4 }
studenci = [zosia, jas, malgosia]

def get_average(dicts, values_labels): # you need to specify which members of zosia, jas, malgosia, etc. you want to count
    values = list(chain.from_iterable((D[label] for label in values_labels) for D in dicts))
    average = sum(values)/len(values)
    return average

print(get_average(studenci, ('zadania', 'quizy', 'testy')))

# >>> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'Returns a list of the "averages" of each dictionary'
def dict_average(*args):
    averages = []
    for arg in args:
        values = arg.values()
        s = 0
        i = 0
        for v in values:
            try:
                s += v
                i += 1
            except TypeError:
                s += 0
        averages.append(s / i)
    return averages
```